# How to create Dictionary<string, string> like collection with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

I am making `Ajax` request that should populate an information dialog which should look something like this:

```
First Name: Jhon
Last Name: Smith
Occupation: programmer
Personal Interests: none
//and so on...
```

Where, `Jhon`, `Smith`, `programmer` taken from a database query to a table which holds information about users. What I want is to return the response formatted like this so I can directly write the output on my view. I tried this:

```
JObject user = new JObject();
connection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
  user.Add(new JProperty("First Name", reader["FirstName"].ToString()));
  user.Add(new JProperty("Last Name", reader["LastName"].ToString()));
  user.Add(new JProperty("Occupation", reader["Occupation"].ToString()));
  use.rAdd(new JProperty("Personal Interests", reader["Hobbies"].ToString()));
}
reader.Close();
```

However I can not use white spaces in property name even if it's `JProperty`. Is there a way to format the data using `JSON.NET` like I want it to be formmated?

Comment: Why do you say you "*cannot use white spaces in the property name even if it's JProperty*"?  Json.Net allows white spaces, so there should not be a problem with that.

Comment: @BrianRogers Hmm, I already forgot what error I got when I tried with white space. Maybe I didn't pay enough attention and jump into conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `Personal##Interests` for the key name and then in the client you simply replace `##` with a space when you're about to display the object.

Comment: It's looks a lot like just a workaround. Not that it's bad. I'm gonna use it if there's not standard way to do this in `JSON.NET` just it seems that there should be some way to format the output with the tools that `JSON.NET` offers. Dunno, maybe I'm wrong. Then I'm gonna use this. But gonan wait some time to see if indeed there's something build in in the library for this case.

Comment: It seems that there's no other suggestions. I've impelented yours and it's doing the job so I'm accpeting the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, cool. Notice that it's a work-around for your work-around. If you didn't use the object's key as a display element you wouldn't need to do that. But it works so happy coding!